# ARGB_8888 bitmap is not visible, while the RGB_565 is

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, config

I face some trouble with creation of my bitmap for a custom analog clock widget. When i use RGB_565 configuration the image is displaying properly, but it has no transparent background. When i'm changing the configuration to ARGB_8888, my image is not displaying at all.

```
   static void updateTime(Context context) {
    int iW = 400, iH = 400;

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
    R.layout.clock22analog);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(iW, iH, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(getPxl(context, 8));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    canvas.drawCircle(iW/2, iH/2, getPxl(context, 100), paint);

    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.analogclock, bitmap);

    ComponentName clockWidget = new ComponentName(context,
    Clock_22_analog.class);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
    .getInstance(context);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(clockWidget, remoteViews);
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hmm this is strange. Do you draw anything else than a circle?

Comment: tried. result is the same.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to clear the canvas.

```
Canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
```